# Use multiple versions of the same database in Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine

Tags: database, symfony1, doctrine

The problem is the folowing: i have 2 databases: ranking_v1 and ranking_v2. Both has the same structure, but different data. Lets say i have a table 'mark'.

In the same action, i want to select from mark using v1, and select from mark using v2, and the show both resusts. How do i do this without writing the schema twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should read this [article about connections](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/cookbook/master-and-slave-connections/en) and set up two connections, a master and a slave connection.